# Apache Http UrlBuilder stripping API version from URL

Tags: java, spring, apache-httpclient-4.x, uribuilder

All,

I have my base url defined in a config like so

> foobar.baseurl = https://api.foobar.com/v3/reporting/

This is passed  as a constructor argument for my Spring bean

```
<bean id="foobarUriBuilder" class="org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder">
    <constructor-arg value="${foobar.baseurl}"/>
</bean>
```

This all works fine, however the [URLBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) strips the `/v3/reporting` part and then when I try to do something like this.

```
    //Set URI path and query params
    uriBuilder.setPath("/fooReports")
              .setParameter("type_of_foo", FOO_TYPE);
```

So the request turns into this

> https://api.foobar.com/fooReports?type_of_foo=bar

Which gives a HTTP 404 naturally.

So how do I stop URIBuilder stripping a part of my URL so I have the correct URL as below?

> https://api.foobar.com/v3/reporting/fooReports?type_of_foo=bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/v3/reporting` is part of the (original) path. When you *set* the path to something else, in this case `/fooReports`, it gets overridden.

You may try to compose the new path with

```
final String originalPath = uriBuilder.getPath();
uriBuilder.setPath(originalPath + "/fooReports")             
          .setParameter("type_of_foo", FOO_TYPE);
```

Comment: Thanks, its a shame they can't add another property like API or version for this situation.